# Add item to menu which pops up when clicking on contact

Tags: android

So, is there a way I can select contact in Androids default contact list and import that contact to my Android application?

I have looked through [How to add button or menu in contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833270/how-to-add-button-or-menu-in-contacts-list) and [Open device contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992564/open-device-contacts-list-at-button-click-event).

The question is: How to get the data to my app? Or how to add menu item (My app) in the menu which pops up when I click on the contact.

I would be pleased if you could tell me how to do this or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: i m little confused abt ur question.what all things u want ??

Comment: i just want to add single item to the menu wich pops up when i click on contact in the Android original contact browser

Comment: like this one?? http://londatiga.net/images/quickactions/quickcontact.jpg